# SQL Server: check if certain date in calendar table falls on a weekend

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, stored-procedures, calendar

I have created a calendar table that contains all the calendar dates of a year, incl. the corresponding quarter / week / month / day etc. information.

The following Select gives me a specific date, here the 17th of March. 
How can I extend the below to check if this falls on a Saturday or Sunday (`weekDayCal = 7 or 1`) and, if true, return the date for the following Monday, otherwise return the 17th ?

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal = 2014) AND (monthCal = 3) AND (dayCal = 17)
```

Many thanks in advance for any help with this, Mike.

Comment: Does your calendar have a sequential id?  Perhaps a `day_of_calendar` field where *every* date is in perfect sequential order?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately only my years, months and weeks have unique IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a `day_of_calendar` style `id` field, where every date is sequentially in order, then this works...

```
SELECT *
  FROM Calendar
 WHERE id = (SELECT id + CASE weekDayCal WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
               FROM Calendar
              WHERE (yearCal = 2014) AND (monthCal = 3) AND (dayCal = 17)
            )
```

If not, then you're going to have to return to using dates in one way or another.

For example...

```
SELECT *
  FROM Calendar
 WHERE realDate = (SELECT realDate + CASE weekDayCal WHEN 7 THEN 2 WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                     FROM Calendar
                    WHERE (yearCal = 2014) AND (monthCal = 3) AND (dayCal = 17)
                  )
```

But then you may as well just use real date calculations.

Comment: Thanks a lot - the second solution is exactly what I was looking for. Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

This fetches rows who fall on sunaday or saturday

```
SELECT *
FROM Calender
WHERE DATEPART(dw, CAST( 
                        CAST(monthCal as VARCHAR(2))+ '-'+
                        CAST(dayCal as VARCHAR(2))+'-'+
                        CAST(yearCal as VARCHAR(4))

                        AS DATETIME
                        )
               ) IN(1,7)
```

Comment: I doubt that `DATENAME(dw,...)` will ever return a value that, even with casting, matches `1` or `7`.

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for at all.  The OP wants the first non-weekend-date on or after `year=2014, month=3, day=17`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Couldnt I just use a CASE statement ? Just trying to keep it as short as possible as I need to check on this for multiple dates in the same procedure.

Comment: datename gets sunday,saturday ... datepart gives 1,7 .. sorry my mistake

Comment: Even the edit makes no sense.  As the `Calendar` table already has a `weekDayCal` field all you have written is: `SELECT * FROM Calendar WHERE weekDayCal IN (1,7)` which doesn't help the OP in anyway at all.  I wish I could down-vote twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work, if you do indeed have a `weekDayCal` column where 1=Sunday, 2 = Monday and 7 = Saturday:

```
SELECT     *
FROM       Calendar
WHERE      (yearCal = 2014) AND (monthCal = 3) AND (
   (dayCal = 17 and weekDayCal not in (1,7)) OR
   (dayCal = 17 + 1 and weekDayCal = 2) OR
   (dayCal = 17 + 2 and weekDayCal = 2))
```